# Installation of conda channel packages with Nexus

Tags: python, proxy

I have a problem to install conda channel packages via Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager (Version: PRO 3.16.1-02).
E.g. the following code

```bsh
conda install pytorch::pytorch==1.1.0 
#is equivalent to:
#conda install --channel pytorch pytorch==1.1.0
```

prints the following error message on the console:

```bsh
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/linux-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
ConnectTimeout(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pytorch/linux-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError
(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7feb2d7f3c50>, 'Connection to conda.anaconda.org timed out. (connect timeout=9.15)'))",),)
```

I believe the problem is that when I specify a conda channel that conda uses https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/linux-64/current_repodata.json instead of a Nexus URL (which does not work as I am behind a proxy and Nexus should do the download for me). My question is how can I make conda use the Nexus URL or somehow make sure that Nexus can download python packages from conda channels?

Kind regards

Michael

Comment: How are you using Conda?  a raw proxy?  community impl?  It is not supported in NXRM out of the box: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-16932.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, indeed they are working on it: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-19866. The solution at the moment is to add a proxy_servers section to the .condarc file with our company's http_proxy and https_proxy and wait until nexus supports conda channels.